# Prove that $\sin(1 + k^3) \not \to 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How can we prove that for $k\in \mathbb{Z}\quad k\to \infty$

$$\sin(1 + k^3) \not \to 0$$

Lately I've encoutered it a couple of times in some OP posted here about series and by the discussion I had, also with expert users, it seems there is not a simple solution.

One possible strategy I had in mind is to show that for

$$\sin(1+k^3) \approx0$$

then

$$\sin(1+(k+1)^3)=\sin(1+k^3+3k^2+3k+1)=\sin(1+k^3)\cos(3k^2+3k+1)+\sin(3k^2+3k+1)\cos(1+k^3)\approx \pm \sin(3k^2+3k+1)$$

and show that $\sin(3k^2+3k+1)$ is "far" from zero.

Comment: I believe the revised version of the question if fully compliant about the rules for asking a good question. I have removed the previous comments but I still have something to suggest: 1) no one is perfect. If a question has some issues, please point them out, in a polite and respectful way; 2) to further stress the previous point, please avoid escalating and make a wise use of the flags, if necessary.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm sorry and I apologize for what happened, I will take in great attention your suggestions for the future in order to avoid this kind of public escalations into personal disputes. Thanks for your time, Regards.

Comment: Nothing personal from my side (if ever this is the nature of the implicit allegation here), but simply a bland, banal, factual reminder of the rules of the site, **that we should all try to follow**, right? That such reminders seem to send some into a whirl of insults is something I deplore, and that I have to endure, but for which I cannot feel responsible. (@JackD'Aurizio When posting comments obviously referring to some users and obviously pretending to address their behaviour, why forget to use the @?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1901539/66096): $\displaystyle \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n |\sin(k^3+1)|$ converges to $\displaystyle\frac 2\pi$ as $n\to \infty$.

If $\sin(k^3+1)$ converged to $0$, so would $|\sin(k^3+1)|$ and Cesaro theorem would imply that $\displaystyle \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n |\sin(k^3+1)|\to 0$, a contradiction.

---

Equidistribution is overkill for the problem at hand. There is a more elementary way, as explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/958350/66096) by Did.

Comment: Thanks I’ll take a look!

Comment: @gimusi There's probably a simpler way (that Did seems to know)...

Comment: You might want to answer this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2692776/determining-if-a-series-is-absolutely-convergent-or-conditionally-convergent-wit, which is where the problem originates.

Comment: @MartinR Yes it is strictly related but this is a specific part of that question, since I can't get an answer I thought it was useful to ask a question about this

Comment: @GabrielRomon we probabily will never know it

Comment: @GabrielRomon Sorry I can't see how the argument by contradiction works with Cesaro since we get from $\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n |\sin(k^3+1)|$ this $\sin(k^3+3k^2+3k+2)$, am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: @GabrielRomon How is the problem linked about https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1901485/505767 related to this one, could you please clarify? Thanks

Comment: @gimusi The only useful part for the problem at hand is: if $P(n)=a_d n^d+\cdots +a_0$  and $a_d$ is rationally independent from $\pi$, then $P(n)$ is equidistributed mod $2\pi$, thus $ \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n |P(k)|\to \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |\sin(t)|dt=\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: @Gimusi Cesaro theorem states that if $u_n$ converges to $l$, then $\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n u_k$ converges to $l$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon ah ok, you are relating the two results, sorry now it is clear!

Comment: @GabrielRomon Well your first solution is almost clear to me a part some minor details that I need to clarify better and as you noticed once we have that $\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n |P(k)|\to \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |\sin(t)|dt=\frac{2}{\pi}$ by Cesaro we are done. I've also noticed that H.H.Rugh in his solution affirm that "One may note that the result (as well as the proof) goes through when replacing $n^2$ by any polynomial in $n$, $p(n)=a_d n^d+\cdots +a_0$  as long as the leading coefficient $a_d$ is rationally independent from $\pi$."

Comment: @GabrielRomon Also the way by the other approach is almost clear to me, a part some minor details that I need to digest better, even if I can't get how to generalize the result by discrete differentiation to the polynomial $(k^3+1)$ but I suppose that this is a some kind of well known result. I've also noticed that in this case fo the extension of the result it is said that "If $P$ is a polynomial with at least one coefficient not a rational multiple of $\pi$, then the sequence $(\sin(P(n)))_n$ does not converge to zero hence the series $\sum\limits_n\sin(P(n))$ diverges".

Comment: @GabrielRomon Why this difference for the generlization of the results, in one case is requested that **"the leading coefficient is rationally independent from π"** and in the other that **"at least one coefficient not a rational multiple of π"**? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

We will show that under certain conditions, sequence $\sin(P(n)),\,n=1, 2, ...$ where $P(n)$ is a "good enough" polynomial, is dense on the interval $[-1, 1]$.

We will use that, for any polynomial $P$,
$$P(x) = a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+a_0 $$
If at least one of the coefficients $a_j$, $j>0$ is irrational, then $P(n)$ is uniformly distributed modulo $1$. In fact, we will only need the fact that the sequence $\{P(n)\}$ is dense in $[0, 1)$.

Let's choose any number from $[-1, 1]$, and let's write it in the form $\sin(a)$.
$$|\sin(a)-\sin(P(n))|=2|\sin(\frac{a-P(n)}{2})\cos(\frac{a+P(n)}{2})| \leq2|\sin(\frac{a-P(n)}{2})| \\= 2|\sin(\frac{a-P(n)}{2}\,\text{mod}\,2\pi)| $$

$$\frac{a-P(n)}{2}\,\text{mod}\,2\pi = 2\pi(\frac{a-P(n)}{4\pi}\,\text{mod}\,1) $$
Recall what we said before, if at least one of $\frac{a_j}{\pi}$ is irrational, for $m\geq j\geq 1$, then $\frac{a-P(n)}{4\pi}\,\text{mod}\,1$ is dense in $[0, 1)$. Then for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can choose $n$, so that: 
$$\frac{a-P(n)}{4\pi}\,\text{mod}\,1 < \frac{\varepsilon}{4\pi}$$

Then:
$$2|\sin(\frac{a-P(n)}{2}\,\text{mod}\,2\pi)|<\varepsilon $$
From which follows that:
$$|\sin(a)-\sin(P(n))|<\varepsilon $$
So the sequence is dense on the interval $[-1, 1]$.

You can see that this is a much stronger result. Since $\frac{1}{\pi}$ is irrational, $\sin(1+k^3)$ is dense in $[-1, 1]$, hence doesn't converge to any real number.

I came up with this proof while reading the book I am learning from right now, it's called "Uniform Distribution of Sequences" by L. Kuipers and H. Niederreiter. You can find the proof that sequences $P(n)$ of that form are uniformly distributed there. It's **Theorem 3.2** on page 27.