# Why is $\{\sin(n): n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ not a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

Why is $\{\sin(n): n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ not a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$?

I am considering $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology but I have no real intuition for finding the limit points of this set.

Comment: Because it's dense in $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: How do we know that?

Comment: [See my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2870017/476484) for example. There should be elementary methods as well.

Comment: $[-1, 1]$ is closed but also dense in $[-1, 1]$, in case someone misunderstands the hint by Jakobian.

Comment: @Improve The set is countable so if it is dense in $[-1,1]$ then any point in that interval not in the set cannot have a neighborhood around it not in the set. We still must prove that the set is dense in that interval but if it is, the result follows.

Comment: Take a look at http://users.auth.gr/~siskakis/sin(n).pdf It is interesting to note that a Google search of this yields some really poor answers including an accepted answer on this site.

Comment: A good way to understand this set is to imagine the set of points $\{(\cos(n),\sin(n)): n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. One can prove these are dense on the unit circle with the pigeonhole principle and the irrationality of $\pi$.